How to logout in SSO sites (with PWA)
I have two websites:

main.com
sub.main.com

Both use the same login system, meaning users log in through the main site (main.com) and can directly access sub.main.com with the same account.
The problem:

sub.main.com has a PWA feature, so I store requests in the cache.
When a user logs out from main.com, I delete the cookies. However, sub.main.com's cache still contains user-specific data that needs to be cleared.

The current solution (and its problem):
Currently, when a user logs out, I redirect them to each subsite like sub.main.com to manually clear the cache. But I think this is a poor solution.
Why do I want to delete the cache?
The cache contains user-related data and site-specific data related to the user.
I don't think this is an ideal solution.
I don't know if I should delete the cache. I want someone to inform me
